# Spark in Foreach

Tags: apache-spark, transformation

```
val a = sc.textFile("/user/cts367689/datagen.txt")

val b = a.map(x => (x.split(",")(0),x.split(",")(2),x.split(4))))

val c = b.filter(x => (x._3.toInt > 500))

c.foreach(x => println(x))
```

or

```
c.foreach {x => {println(x)}}
```

I am not getting the expected output when i use for-each statement.I want output to be print one in a line but not sure what wrong in my code.

Comment: Did you try to read the official documentation before asking the question ? Your answers lies there.

Comment: Got the answer,c.collect.foreach(x=>println(x))..thanls!!

Comment: This is not absolutely correct.

Comment: I am new to spark not sure what the exact answer..

Comment: The answer you have found has limitations. It will print out your RDD content. But when your RDD doesn't fit in the driver this will not work. That's why I said read the documentation. This is where I learned Spark.

Comment: Thanks for information!

Comment: @eliasah post an answer :)

Comment: @T.Gawęda done ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this have been answered already a couple of times before but here we go again and from the Official [Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) :

**Printing elements of an RDD**

One common idiom is attempting to print out the elements of an RDD using `rdd.foreach(println)` or `rdd.map(println)`. On a single machine, this will generate the expected output and print all the RDD’s elements.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2,3),(2,3,4)))
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> rdd.foreach(println)
// (1,2,3)
// (2,3,4)
```

However, in cluster mode, the output to stdout being called by the executors is now writing to the executor’s stdout instead, not the one on the driver, so stdout on the driver won’t show these!

To print *all elements on the driver*, one need to `collect()` the data back  to the driver node thus:

```
scala> rdd.collect().foreach(println)
// (1,2,3)
// (2,3,4)
```

And here is the limitation. If your data doesn't fit on the driver, this can cause the driver to run out of memory, though, because collect() fetches the entire RDD to a single machine; Thus causing your driver to blow.

If you only need to print a few elements of the RDD, a safer approach is to use the take():

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Range(1, 1000000000))
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> rdd.take(100).foreach(println)
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 8
// 9
// 10
// [...]
```

**PS:** A small note concerning the `foreach` method. `foreach` runs a function on each element of the dataset. This method is usually done for side effects such as updating an Accumulator or interacting with external storage systems.

I hope that this answers your question.